# ogr2ogr list of layers created

Tags: gdal, postgresql, ogr2ogr

Using a command such as the following:-

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL "postgresql:..." \
-lco SCHEMA=my_schema \
foo.xlsx
```

on a Excel sheet with multiple tabs will create multiple tables in schema **my_schema** based upon the tab names

Is there a way of getting ogr2ogr to list/output the name of the tables created? The alternative is to do a before/after query on **my_schema** in Postgres but I'd rather  avoid this if possible and keep it all at the command line.

Just in case this helps anyone, a python snippet I wrote post answer:-

```py
import subprocess
import re

command = ['ogrinfo', '-nomd', '-nogeomtype','my_file.xlsx']

try:
    result = subprocess.run(command,check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError  as error:
        print(f"ogrinfo Error: {error.stderr.decode('utf-8')}")
        exit()


layers = []
for layer in result.stdout.split('\n'):
    match = re.search(r'^[-0-9]+: (.*)$',layer)
    if match:
        matched = re.sub(r'\-#\\', '_',match.group(1))
        layers.append(matched.lower())

print(layers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ogr2ogr by default does not change the names of the layers and you should get a list with

```
ogrinfo -nomd -nogeomtype foo.xlsx
```

However, the PostGIS driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html launders some names automatically

> -lco LAUNDER=YES This converts to lower case and converts some special characters like “-” and “#” to “_”. If “NO” exact names are preserved. The default value is “YES”.

Another option might be to use the PGDump driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pgdump.html and have a look at the beginning of the generated text file where the CREATE TABLE statements are. The names there would appear laundered. But then you should load the data from SQL as a separate step or just re-run the command by using PG as target.

Comment: Perfect: ogrinfo -nomd -nogeomtype flags get me closer to what I want

Comment: Thanks, I improved my answer. You can also try the PGDump method for seeing the laundered names. Maybe adding `-limit 1` would make the output shorter and response faster but I have not tested that.